# Where can I find literary agents that publish books by minors?

Tags: publishing

I'm writing a book and I would like to know about  some literary agents that publish books by a child.  I write many stories (I'm writing as I get ideas) but this is my first book, and I would love to publish it for the world to see. I need a literary agent but I don't know where to find one.

Comment: Do you mean literary agents?

Comment: Is this your own account, or was it set up by a parent who supervises your use of it?

Comment: Set up by parent

Comment: @WritingNerd thank you for that clarification.

Comment: You say you want to publish it for the world to see, which these days you could do on your own (though you'd get less visibility).  Are you specifically looking to sign up with a publisher, or are you looking for an agent to guide you and hook you up with editors and other professionals, or what?  Thanks for any details you can add.

Comment: Sing up with a publisher

Answer (score 1):

Literary agents are the stepping stone between authors and publishers (and in my opinion, an absolute necessity until you have a long-term deal with a publisher, which happens rarely).

There are several resources to consider both nationally and internationally. I would point you to two websites. The first is JaneFriedman.com "How to Write a Query Letter," and the second is pw.org/literary_agents (poets and writers). They keep up to date better than others I've tried. Expect about 100 rejection letters.